# open ajax call in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sending form data along with some json to print.php , but i want print.php to open in a new tab , rather that it being called in the back ground.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "print.php",
            data: { formData : $("#bill_print").serializeArray() , lab : jsonLab , others : jsonOthers},
             success: function(response) {

             }
      });
```

is there a way to send json data along with form submit using ajaxForm/ajaxSubmiit ?

Comment: This is very confusing, do you want to open a new window with the result if the ajax OR do you want to call the ajax in the new window  ?

Comment: @Craig . To make things clear , print.php is a bill layout that is being printed using window.print() . ajaxForm() opens print.php in the same tab which is exactly the way I want , but since I have some JSON data to be sent along with the form , I am unable to use ajaxForm. I just want print.php to open is same/new tab once I submit the form with ajax

Comment: `ajaxForm()` is not a native jQuery plugin.  Are you perhaps using [this plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)?  If so, you should show exactly how you have it set up that it produces "exactly the way I want"

Comment: ajaxForm() was my previous attempt when I just had form data, I had set it up. Now that I have json to send as well, I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: @sai I understand that, but unless we see what you're doing that produced what you wanted originally, it's hard offer a suggestion that will still produce that result with the new requirements.

Comment: @patrick , the link that you suggested might solve my problem , I'll try and get back.

Comment: @PatrickQ , thanks for the link mate , that's what I intended to do , i just wanted to do a normal form submit with ajax , but that hack did it without the need of ajax.

Comment: @sai Glad to help